# Recent Achievement Indicator

Tags: support, bug

The Recent Achievement Indicator on both the main site and the meta site, aren't showing up to the minute info.  For example in my case, I got 2 upvotes yesterday, and 1 about 3 hours ago, and all aren't showing.  Is that a problem in the system?

[image]

Comment: I'ld think given the current time window and the recent database maintenance, you should wait it out and see if it changes...

Comment: @Braiam Its not the same.  My problem is that it does not show achievements, eg. upvotes, badges, etc.

Comment: Everything is caused by the same issue, the top bar use the same method for pushing notifications. Ah, btw, is fixed (or at least seems so).

Comment: It's a symptom of the same issue - we had problems in our redis caching layer that prevented updates to those dropdowns.